# Filters logic should be on frontend or backend?

Tags: java, reactjs, rest

I’m creating a web application

Frontend - reactjs and backend java.

Frontend and backend communicate with each other via rest.

On UI I show a list of items. And I need to filter them for some params.

**Option 1: filter logic is on front end**

In this case I just need to make a get call to backend and get all items. 
After user choose some filter option filtering is happening on ui.

**Pros**: for that I don’t need to send data to back end and wait for response. Speed of refreshing the list should be faster.

**Cons**: If I will need multiple frontend clients. Let’s say a mobile app. Than I need to create filters again on this app too.

**Option 2: filter logic is on back end**

In this case I get all list items when app is loading. After user changes the filter options I need to send a get request with filters params and wait for response.
After that update a list of items on UI.

**Pros**: filter logic is written only once.

**Cons**: Speed probably will be much slower. Because it takes time to send request and get a result back.

**Question**: Where the filter logic should be? In frontend or in backend? Or maybe what is a best practice?

Comment: You forgot the most important criterion: if the list needs to be filtered, it's probably that it's too large to be digested. If it's too large, loading the complete list from the backend uses too much bandwidth, takes too much time, consumes too much memory on the backend and the frontend.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Filter and limit on the back end. If you had a million records, and a hundred thousand users trying to access those records at the same time, would you really want to send a million records to EVERY user? It'd kill your server and user experience (waiting for a million records to propagate from the back end for every user AND then propagate on the front end would take ages when compared to just getting 20-100 records and then clicking a (pagination) button to retrieve the next 20-100). On top of that, then to filter a million records on the front-end would, again, take a very long time and ultimately not be very practical.

From a real world stand point, most websites have some sort of record limit: Ebay = 50-200 records, Amazon = ~20, Target = ~20... etc. This ensures quick server responses and a smooth user experience for every user.

Comment: What about a search filter by item name with autocompletion? Everytime user add new letter in search box I need to send a get request to server and get a response. In this case searching filter is also better to implement in back end?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't become right to overload everything just because you happen to use auto-completion. And you shouldn't send a request every time the user enters a new letter. You should send a request when the user stops typing for more than, say, 400 milliseconds. If I'm searching for "JavaScript", I don't care about the results for J, Ja, Jav, Java, Javas, etc.

Comment: Pretty much what JB says. You can use lodash's debounce to delay sending a request based upon a certain time between keypresses: https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce. The thing to consider is that your back-end should be the source of truth (meaning, it should always serve the front-end with requested filtered/limited data). That way the front-end and back-end are always 1:1.

Comment: What if you do filter on back-end and front-end?

Comment: Depends on how large the dataset is and the order of operations. If you filter on the client are you filtering **ALL** related data or are you filtering just what happens to be available to the client? Answering that should determine whether or not the dual filters suits your needs. But, again, if you have millions of records, it doesn’t make much sense to force a device, like an iPad, to handle filtration nor does it make much sense to serve millions of records from the backend to the front end.

Comment: Lastly, one thing you won’t find on client side filtration is cacheing. Databases can cache results to speed up querying, clients can’t.

Answer (score 22):

Most likely begin with the frontend (unless you're dealing with huge amounts of data):

1. Implement filtering on the frontend (unless for some reason it's easier to do it on the backend, which I find unlikely).
2. Iterate until filtering functionality is somewhat stable.
3. Analyze your traffic, see if it makes sense to put the effort into implementing backend filtering. See what percentage of requests are actually filtered, and what savings you'd be getting from backend filtering.
4. Implement (or not) backend filtering depending on the results of #3.

As a personal note, the accepted answer is terrible advice:

- "If you had a million records, and a hundred thousand users trying to access those records at the same time"; nothing is forcing the hundred thousand users to use filtering, your system should be able to handle that doomsday scenario. Backend filtering should be just an optimization, not a solution.
- once you do filtering on the backend you'll probably want to do pagination as well; this is not a trivial feature if you want consistent results.
- doing backend filtering is likely to become much more complex than just frontend filtering; you should be aware that you're going to spend a significant amount of time (not only for the initial implementation but also for ongoing maintenance) and ask yourself if it's not premature optimization.

TL/DR: Do wherever is easier for you and don't worry about it until it makes sense to start optimizing.

Comment: I like the different perspective this answer provides.

Comment: This answer is what I do, and now I'm in a situation that needs optimization. I wonder whether it is ok to sacrifice simplicity and maintainability over optimization.

Comment: @dhidy - if you need the optimisation and it comes at the cost of simplicity, then just do it. Don't see it as a hassle, see it as a challenge - "how do I optimise my code while keeping it as maintainable as possible"?

Answer (score 16):

This depends on the size of your data.
For eg: If you are having a large amount of data, it is better to implement the filter logic on the backend and let the db perform the operations.

In case, you have less amount of data, you can do the filter logic on the front end after getting the data.

Let us understand this by an example.
Suppose you have an entity having 1,00,000 records and you want to show it in a grid.
In this case it is better to get 10 records on every call and show it in a grid.
If you want to perform any filter operation on this, it is better to make a query for the db on the backend and get the results

In case it you have just 1000 records in your entity, it will be beneficial to get all the data and do all the filter operations on the frontend.

Comment: What about a search filter by item name with autocompletion? Everytime user add new letter in search box I need to send a get request to server and get a response. In this case searching filter is also better to implement in back end?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Suppose a user enters term 'G' in the search filter, you need to pass 'G' in query to your backend and let ur db perform the operation to get the names starting with 'G'. In this case also when you have 1 million records and fields are distinct then this will be proper to use. Because more chances are that user enters G , then he will select the name from the autocompletion and not type further. Thats why we provide autocompletion right? To limit user typing

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the specific requirements of your application, but in my opinion the safer bet would be the back-end.

Considering you need filtering in the first place, I assume you have enough data so that paging through it is required. In this case, you need to have the filtering on the back-end.

Lets say you have a page size of 20. After you apply the filter you would expect to have a page of 20 entities that match that specific filtering criteria in the UI. This can't be achieved if you fetch 20 entities, store them in the front-end and afterwards apply the filter on them.

Also, if you have enough data, fetching all of it in the front-end will be impossible due to memory constraints.

Comment: What about a search filter by item name with autocompletion? Everytime user add new letter in search box I need to send a get request to server and get a response. In this case searching filter is also better to implement in back end?

Comment: Yes, still on the back-end. If you have a lot of data you should implement the filtering logic on the persistence layer of you back-end. This would allow you to reuse highly optimized data structures for your scenario (i.e inverted indexes from Elasticsearch to implement a 'starts with' query).