# Big Grid and a lot of data using Spring / Angular / PrimeNG

Tags: angular, spring-boot, primeng

Big Grid in a Web App - Our use case is to present a grid of about 120cols and varying # of rows (a few thousand). Need guidance:

Best way to design ?
Performance - how can I render and also present the data in the grid quickly ?
Filtering functionality - our users will need to filter the data. We've obviously developed filter functionality on smaller grids...but reaching out for suggestions on this big grid.
We are currently on Angular 9 (working on upgrading to 11) and using Prime NG.

Should we present all of the data on the front end and let the front end manage the data/filtering etc.. or look at server side pagination and filtering ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of discussion & thoughts on the internet connected to this topic. But there is no clear (I mean no one right) answer. It depends case by case. And whatever you choose, you need to verify/test and maybe reconsider and change the solution. Different "bricks" play important role like:

1. e.g. is importance of all 120 cols the same, or some are more important then other? / same question for rows -> so you can less important data lazy load when needed.
2. how user(s) will typically work with given data table? like just see/scroll and occasionally order/filter or typical user work is filtering/ordering?
3. how many users will use this table? each user in different way or similarly -> so you can cache data on the backend to not overload database
4. will you use endless scroll or paginator (also search for discussion and best practices)
5. performance of your backend
6. how often are change data on your backend
7. are you typical users on the LAN or over Wireless net?
8. ...

Generally there are three basic solution:

1. load all data to the client and do all sorting/filtering on the client
2. do sort/filter just on the backend (e.g. Primeng Table - lazy: https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/lazy)
3. Some combination of these two above - you can e.g. load all columns and just certain number of records (default e.g. 500 / can be configurable by user in the client) to the client and lazy load next X when needed.

Some links:

- [Filters logic should be on frontend or backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346685/filters-logic-should-be-on-frontend-or-backend)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/ba0jf1/should_data_filtering_be_done_backendfrontend
- If you are using REST API: https://medium.com/@guillaume.viguierjust/paging-sorting-filtering-and-retrieving-specific-fields-in-your-restful-api-a0d289bc574a