# How to Sort, Filter, Search the data which I get from REST API (JSON Form) and Update the UI immediately using State Management Like BLOC or PROVIDER?

Tags: flutter, sorting, flutter-layout, full-text-search, flutter-state

This is the data from the API:

```
  {
  "httpStatus": "OK",
  "httpStatusCode": 200,
  "success": true,
  "message": "Successfully fetched all agents.",
  "apiName": "Get all agents.",
  "data": [
      {
        "id": 1
        "prod_name": "Apple"
        "price": 20
        "rating": 4.5
        "category": "Fruits"     
       },
       {
        "id": 10
        "prod_name": "Potato"
        "price": 10
        "rating": 5
        "category": "Vegetables"     
       },
       {
        "id": 7
        "prod_name": "Instant Mushroom Soup"
        "price": 37.5
        "rating": 4.0
        "category": "Packaged/Frozen"     
       }
   ]
   }
```

Now, after getting the above data from the API, and displaying it on the screen in the list, how to search through the names of products, sort them in orders of price low to high or high to low, and sort them through ratings. Filter them using category, **and immediately update the UI using state management with BLOC or Provider, just as standard E-Commerce app functionality. I couldn't think of a way to do this, as I am new to state management.**

**PS: Suggest an edit if there's anything wrong with the question**

*Thanks for the help in advance :)*

Answer (score 0):

From your question you mentioned about "E-Commerce app", which I assume will involve large amount of products.

In this case, Sort Filter Search function is better to be handled on backend for a better performance. Refer [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52346865/12284067).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you need to sort or fetch data from API use this format

List result=[ ]; search(String keyword){ result = await ApiService.search(keyword): result.sort ((a, b)=> a.name.compareTo(b.name)); update;

}